# pynput.keyboard Listener fails on macOS

Tags: python, join, listener, pynput, keylogger

I'm just trying to make a simple keyboard listener that prints whatever key I press (pynput.keyboard.Listener). Here is my code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener

def on_press(k):
    print(k)


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as lis:
    lis.join()
```

But, when I run it just does nothing. So I press *CTRL+C* and it shows up these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/py/KeyLogger/keylogger.py", line 8, in <module>
    lis.join()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pynput/_util/__init__.py", line 252, in join
    super(AbstractListener, self).join(*args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 1044, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 1060, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Here with anaconda/Python3.8 instead of Python3.7:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/py/KeyLogger/keylogger.py", line 8, in <module>
    lis.join()
File "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pynput/_util/__init__.py", line 252, in join
    super(AbstractListener, self).join(*args)
  File "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 1011, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 1027, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

It seems the error is when I tell the listener to start. I've been searching for similar issues (threading and join() issues, mostly) but I haven't found the answer to my problem. ¿Could it be a **pynput** problem?

Thanks.